# Git deleted "unnamed local" aka deattached HEAD branch after switching to another branch

Tags: git, branch, local, atlassian-sourcetree, temporary

[Image I'm asking about](https://i.stack.imgur.com/b4v1W.jpg)

I was working on a project and realized that my current approach isn't working (Number 2 on the picture). So I went back to an old commit (Number 1) and started working.

Git/Sourcetree apparently created a new branch for the new commits I produced up to number 3. I switched back to another branch to test something but when I wanted to go back to the branch with number 3 at the end the branch wasn't there anymore.

Is there a way to get this "local temporary" branch back?

Thank you for your help!!

Comment: I do not get how a branch disappears without any delete action..

Comment: It seems you were on detached HEAD when you run `git checkout commit1`. You could run `git reflog` to find it out and then use `git checkout -b <branchname> <commit>` to create a real branch from that commit.

Comment: @DogukanZengin was using sourcetree. The program showed me a new branch I commited to multiple times. It didn't show a name for it though.

Comment: @ElpieKay Thank you so much! I found the commit with git reflog and created a new actual branch with it! 7h of work saved :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like I was on detached HEAD when you run `git checkout commit1`. You could run `git reflog` to find the old commit and then use `git checkout -b <branchname> <commit>` to create a real branch from that commit.